# MongoDB: Can I Manually Delete The Collections Inside /var/lib/mongodb Without Breaking Anything?

Tags: mongodb

Due to stupid negligence on my part I forgot to change the MongoDB path. As a result, my collections were stored in `/var/lib/mongodb`.

As I was filling my collections MongoDB hang. Then I realized that `sda1` is full:

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       23571900  22350540       908 100% /
```

Typing `du -h /var/lib/mongodb/` returns:

```
351M    /var/lib/mongodb/journal
20M     /var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data
16G     /var/lib/mongodb/
```

I cannot restart MongoDB. Typing `sudo service mongodb start` returns:

```
Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service not found.
```

I don't care about losing the collections I have created. I can easily recreate them.

**Question**: Can I manually delete the collection I see inside `/var/lib/mongodb` without breaking anything?

```
collection-0-5532744735691012757.wt   index-24-5532744735691012757.wt  _mdb_catalog.wt
collection-23-5532744735691012757.wt  index-32-5532744735691012757.wt  mongod.lock
collection-2-5532744735691012757.wt   index-3-5532744735691012757.wt   sizeStorer.wt
collection-31-5532744735691012757.wt  index-54-5532744735691012757.wt  storage.bson
collection-4-5532744735691012757.wt   index-5-5532744735691012757.wt   WiredTiger
collection-53-5532744735691012757.wt  index-58-5532744735691012757.wt  WiredTigerLAS.wt
collection-57-5532744735691012757.wt  index-61-5532744735691012757.wt  WiredTiger.lock
collection-64-5532744735691012757.wt  index-65-5532744735691012757.wt  WiredTiger.turtle
collection-6-5532744735691012757.wt   index-7-5532744735691012757.wt   WiredTiger.wt
diagnostic.data               index-8-5532744735691012757.wt
index-1-5532744735691012757.wt        journal
```

Comment: Do you want to complete remove your data or are you asking about removing individual files? Wiping your `dbPath` and restarting is fine; removing individual files will be problematic.

Comment: I'm asking about deleting `collection-53-5532744735691012757.wt` for example.

Comment: Deleting individual files in a WiredTiger `storage.dbPath` is definitely a **no**. WiredTiger performs integrity checks on startup and `mongod` will be unable to start if there is a mismatch in the expected files or checksums. Recovering a compromised `dbPath` is not straightforward and definitely a situation to avoid. What are your versions of O/S and MongoDB? The service error is likely because the service is named `mongod` and not `mongodb`. Try: `sudo service mongod start`.